# new Date() returns a different time

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am currently trying to learn JavaScript and today I was exploring the "new Date()" function. However, during the process I noticed that if I assign a date to a variable and decompile it into pieces and try to compile it again the exact time is not the same. Shouldn't be "getDate" be equal to "currentTime"? I would be grateful if someone can point out if I made a mistake somewhere or if not from what exactly comes the difference.

PS: Every time I run the snippet the difference in minutes between the two seems to be inconsistent.

```js
var getDate= new Date();

var currentYear = getDate.getFullYear();
var currentMonth = getDate.getMonth();
var currentDay = getDate.getDate();
var currentHour = getDate.getHours();
var currentMinutes = getDate.getMinutes();
var currentMiliseconds = getDate.getMilliseconds();

var currentTime =  new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, currentHour, currentMinutes, currentMiliseconds);  

console.log(getDate.toString());
console.log(currentTime.toString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mistakenly passed milliseconds before seconds, so the [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) treated the milliseconds as seconds.

Milliseconds goes from 0 to 999, so for most of the time, the time you created is several minute later than the actual time:

```js
var getDate= new Date();

var currentYear = getDate.getFullYear();
var currentMonth = getDate.getMonth();
var currentDay = getDate.getDate();
var currentHour = getDate.getHours();
var currentMinutes = getDate.getMinutes();
// you've missed
var currentSeconds = getDate.getSeconds();
var currentMilliseconds = getDate.getMilliseconds();

var currentTime =  new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, currentHour, currentMinutes, currentSeconds, currentMilliseconds);  

console.log(getDate.toString());
console.log(currentTime.toString());
```

Comment: I think, this is a sign that I must go to bed. Thank you very much for pointing it out.